# Confused on how to make questions "better"

Tags: discussion, downvotes, asking-questions, post-ban

It seems like no matter what I do, my questions always get downvoted. I can put 3+ hours into research, screenshots explaining why it's not a duplicate question, and give all my code and I still get downvoted and banned on asking questions.

I feel like Stack Overflow was intended to be a much more friendly place, but a lot of the people I've run into are not so friendly. Why? I can't get the help I need if my questions constantly get downvoted and I'm not sure what else to do to fix them.

Comment: I notice that you have not yet [taken the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Perhaps that's the place to start?

Comment: And after that you can read: [Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints).

Comment: It is funny that you use a screenshot to *prove* to us that your question is not a duplicate, which it clearly isn't, because that screenshot shows **TWO** errors pointed out by the IDE, which you obviously didn't address nor mention in your question. I'm sure the solution for those two problems are covered by a couple of duplicates as well.

Comment: Did the OP just delete their account?

Comment: @RobertColumbia looks like it, yes.
 There is a user deleted event in the timeline (10K only)  https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47607354/timeline credited to the community User. So I assume this is a user who requested deletion from their profile.

Answer (score 3):

For one, you could make your answers more readable. For instance, [java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo java.lang.Class has no zero argument constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47607354/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-activity-componentinfo-java-la). Some of us are lazy and although we want to help you (because we are nice people), we would rather move on to a question that is easier to read. Throwing large amounts of code will not help you get upvotes in your questions.

Comment: I totally get that, and I figured posting the error as the title would be the better route to go than just stating that I was having an error I couldn't figure out. And I put large amounts of code because I've been downvoted for not having enough code. There's like this weird balance I can't quite strike.

Comment: This may help with that problem: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Don't worry too much about it. Just post code that you think is relevant, and someone will post in the comments if they want more info.

Comment: @Meepo: I think it's *much* better to put the effort into constructing a minimal but complete example. That way a) everyone can run the code; b) you don't just need to *think* the code is relevant - you'll have proved it.

Comment: "Some of us are lazy" - Hey! ... yeah alright, true enough.